# Global variable in javascript doesn't changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

```
    $check = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: $name + "=" + $value,
        success: function(data){
            $check = data;
            alert($check);
        }
    });

    alert($check);
```

The first msg is "Hello"

**The second msg is ""** Why ?

Comment: When you say "first" and "second" are you talking about time sequence or code line sequence? It makes big difference. In the above code, by time sequence, first message should be empty and later one when your ajax call returned, the second message should be  "Hello".

Comment: This code executes once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.ajax` is an asynchronous function, it returns immediately and calls the `success` callback when the success response is received.

Therefore, When the `alert($check)` at the bottom of your code is executed, the value of `$check` is not yet modified by the callback of `ajax`. That's why you see the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

jquery ajax function by default is async. so the execute dosent wait for the functions value to be returned. so mayb because you are working on local development server. and the ajax post request is fast and you are returning word hello in response of you post request so the first alert message is "Hello" 
and then the execution continues and returns alerts you of the `$chek` local value again